# What are the characteristics of people living in Kaliyuga?

Tags: kali-yuga

What are the characteristics of people who live in Kaliyuga , how are people in Kaliyuga different from those living in previous Yugas ?

Comment: Read from doha 95 of uttarkand ramcharitmanas

Answer (score 5):

There is a sharp deterioration of moral standing of people in Kali Yuga compared to earlier Yuga.

Kali Yuga

> These are the characteristics of Kaliyuga: violence, jealousy,
> falsehood, deception and slaughter of ascetics. These are the
> characteristics of Kali age which people inherit.

**Vayu Purana I.58.31**

> Affected by the traits of the Age, entire dharma deteriorates. It is
> doubtful whether the livelihood (of the people) can be achieved even
> by putting up mental strain, physical exertion or prayers.

**Vayu Purana I.58.32**

> In Kali Age, there are fatal diseases. There is perpetual fear of
> hunger. There is terrible danger of draught. Vision is blurred and
> rendered perverse.

**Vayu Purana I.58.33**

> In Kali age people are unrighteous, unmindful of the rules of conduct,
> fierce in anger but deficient in power and splendor. They always utter
> falsehood.

**Vayu Purana I.58.35**